# Allow pasting to a non-editable element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, copy, paste

"editable" nodes (whether they're form elements or elements with `@contenteditable` set) allow pasting, that is they both trigger a `paste` when `C-v`/`⌘-v` is pressed and enable a `Paste` item in a contextual menu on right-click (and I guess they trigger a `paste` on middle-click in many linux environments).

It's possible to intercept left clicks and focus an editable element nearby to allow/intercept keyboard-based pastes, but I'm also looking for middle-click and context menus to behave and enable pasting in specific context (elements which kinda sorta look and feel editable but technically are not).

An example of the issue can be seen playing with DocumentCloud's [visualsearch](http://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/): it looks like a big input with tags but is a sequence of items and small (10 px wide) inputs. Left-clicking in the white space at the end focuses the closest input, but right- or middle-clicking at the same place does not enable pastability, one has to click specifically on an input for this to work.

SO's tags editor somewhat works around the issue by having a single big input filling up the end of the area (but no way to insert new tags at other places), but the issue exists if one middle- or right-clicks between tags or on a tag.